# discord.js better-sqlite3 addition is not actually adding the result from a previous const

Tags: node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

```
if (command == "tgive") {
      //Get their current balance
    const grab = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args[1]}`).get();
    //Grab the value from the first input after the second. Ex: eco tgive 5 Juliana
    const pointsToAdd = parseInt(args[0]);
    //Add the two values from the database and the args[0] input
    const result = +grab.bal + +pointsToAdd;
    //Replace the curret value from column bal in table ${args[1]}, with the const result
    sql.prepare(`REPLACE INTO ${args[1]} (bal) VALUES ('${result}');`).run();
    message.channel.send(`You have ${grab.bal}`);

}
});
```

Inside of the database "Juliana", the value of column `bal` is `420`, however, whenever I run this command with the value of `5`, I get `You have 420`, instead of `You have 425`, meaning that the command did not add in the value from `const result`

Comment: Ah, also another note. I just noticed this now: The Sqlite3 database is adding in another set with different values, so it is technically adding in the inputted value, however, its adding in more lines. So technically, I get something like this inside of the DB Browser: 

``bal``
``Filter``
``1 [420]``
``2 [5567]``
``3 [425]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const grab = sql.prepare(`SELECT bal FROM ${args[1]}`).get();
```

When this line of code runs, it retrieves the value from the database and makes a *copy* of it. That means that when the database is updated, the value of `grab` isn't.

If you want to get the new balance, then you'll need to query the database again.

Comment: Ah, I put ``sql.prepare(`UPDATE ${args[1]} SET bal = ${result} WHERE rowid = 1;`).run();`` and it seems to work, thank you!